# Kotlin and Android TextWatcher with CharSequence/String replace functions

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm just playing around with Kotlin on my project and I came to strange problem... When trying to convert custom `EditText` Android studio stops responding. When I tried to convert it part by part, it stops responding when converting this piece of code:

```
private TextWatcher editor = new TextWatcher() {

    long newMicro = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        s = s.toString().replace(".", "")
                .replace(",", "")
                .replace("$", "");

        try {
            newMicro = Long.parseLong(s.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            newMicro = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        removeTextChangedListener(editor);
        setMicroUnits(newMicro);
        addTextChangedListener(editor);
    }
};
```

Have you experienced such a behavior? I'm unable to reimplement this `TextWatcher` in Kotlin since I cannot perform neither

`CharSequence.toString().replace()`

nor

[`CharSequence.replace()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html)

**Any idea how to implement custom TextWatcher in Kotlin?** This is code I've prepared:

```
val editor = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Problem occurs while working with kotlin version `1.1.2-4` on Android Studio 3 Preview 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like it's not only my problem, that `TextWatcher` hangs while converting. It stops responding every time. My problem was, that I was unable to use Kotlins `String.replace()`

Solution was just to use proper versions of Kotlin
AndroidStudio 3.0 preview 6 with `kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'`

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried to convert your code to Kotlin in Android Studio and it hanged as well. I assume it's problem with nullable parameters in TextWatcher interface methods.

Anyway, this piece of code must be what you are looking for:

```
private val editor = object : TextWatcher {

    var newMicro: Long = 0

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val text = s.toString().replace(".", "")
                .replace(",", "")
                .replace("$", "")

        try {
            newMicro = java.lang.Long.parseLong(text)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            newMicro = 0
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        removeTextChangedListener(this)
        setMicroUnits(newMicro)
        addTextChangedListener(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for your time, only problem was usage of incorrect kotlin version. Studio sill freezes and nullable parameters are not problem.